# Making Haskell code more idiomatic (440 Hz tone)

Tags: haskell, audio

Here's what I have. It generates a 5 second [Au file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_file_format) with a 440 Hz sine wave, inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572651/using-python-to-play-two-sine-tones-at-once).

```
-- file: tone.hs

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BLC
import Data.Binary.Put

-- au format header: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_file_format
header :: Double -> Integer -> Integer -> Put
header dur rate bps = do
  putLazyByteString $ BLC.pack ".snd"
  putWord32be 24
  putWord32be $ fromIntegral $ floor $ fromIntegral bps * dur * fromIntegral rate
  putWord32be 3
  putWord32be $ fromIntegral rate
  putWord32be 1


-- audio sample data
samples :: Double -> Integer -> Integer -> Double -> Double -> Put
samples dur rate bps freq vol =
    foldl1 (>>) [put i | i <- [0..numSamples-1]]
  where
    numSamples = floor $ fromIntegral rate * dur
    scale i = 2 * pi * freq / fromIntegral rate * fromIntegral i
    sample i = vol * sin (scale i)
    coded samp = floor $ (2 ^ (8*bps-1) - 1) * samp
    put i = putWord16be $ coded $ sample i


freq = 440 :: Double    -- 440 Hz sine wave
dur = 5 :: Double       -- played for 5 seconds
rate = 44100 :: Integer -- at a 44.1 kHz sample rate
vol = 0.8 :: Double     -- with a peak amplitude of 0.8
bps = 2 :: Integer      -- at 16 bits (2 bytes) per sample

main =
    BL.putStr $ runPut au
  where
    au = do
      header dur rate bps
      samples dur rate bps freq vol
```

If you're running Linux, you can listen with `runghc tone.hs | aplay`. For other operating systems, you can probably redirect output to a `.au` file and play it in an audio player.

How can I make this code more idiomatic? For example:

- I wrote `fromIntegral` all over the place. Could I have avoided that?
- Should/could I be using a different package for outputting the binary data?
- Am I using reasonable types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing really bad here. `foldl1 (>>) [put i | i <- [0..numSamples-1]]` is equivalent to `mapM_ put [0 .. numSamples-1]`. Rate should just be a `Double`, that gets you rid of the `fromIntegral`s.

`Data.Binary.Put` is really fine for binary output. One might question whether it's good to write the samples to the monad right away (it might be more flexible to keep them as directly-accessible floating-point values in some suitable container (like chunks of `Data.Vector.Storable`) and only `put` them from some generic function right in the end), but performance-wise your approach is actually very efficient. And since it's not `IO` your using, you can always get the data back in a safe, pure way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the type checker to help you remove the `fromIntegral` calls:

1. Comment out your type signature for `header`
2. Also comment out your `main` definition
3. Load the code into ghci
4. Use `:t header` to see what GHC comes up with for the type signature of `header`.

Doing this yields:

```
*Main> :t header
header
  :: (Integral a1, Integral a2, RealFrac a) =>
     a -> a2 -> a1 -> PutM ()
```

This suggests that we can remove the `fromIntegral` on the `rate` and `bps` parameters, and indeed, this definition of `header` typechecks:

```
header dur rate bps = do
  putLazyByteString $ BLC.pack ".snd"
  putWord32be 24
  putWord32be $ floor $ bps * dur * rate
  putWord32be 3
  putWord32be $ fromIntegral rate
  putWord32be 1
```

and the type is now:

```
*Main> :t header
header :: (Integral a, RealFrac a) => a -> a -> a -> PutM ()
```

Note that we still have a fromIntegral on `rate` which we could eliminate by using `floor`, e.g.:

```
  putWord32be $ floor rate
```

which changes the type of `header` to `RealFrac a => a -> a -> a -> PutM ()`.

The main point is to use the type checker to help you understand what the most general type signature a function could have.

Comment: Making the signatures more general is not necessarily a good idea: this often makes it harder for GHC to generate efficient code, which for audio applications definitely matters.